# Can I convert a JSON string to a Flex ArrayCollection in without changing the item order?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5

Regarding this issue, I have generated dynamically string from Java .each time string format change , for example String format is

```
[{"BranchName":"Corporate Office","Date":"08\/03\/2013","SPName":"Pharmacy","SPAmount_5-00%":"100.00","SPVATAmount_5-00%":"15.00","SPOtherCharges_5-00%":"30.00","SPAmount_14-50%":"200.00","SPVATAmount_14-50%":"39.00","SPOtherCharges_14-50%":"71.00","SPColTPA":"100.00","SPColChequeDD":"50.00","SPHdfcCC":"100.00","SPIdbiCC":"100.00","SPColCash":"50.00","Difference":"55.00"},
```

But when I convert array collection with following code .

```
var rawData:String = String(event.result); 
var arr:Array = (JSON.decode(rawData) as Array);
var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(arr);
```

but array collection order changed as default sort like [Branch, Date, Difference,.. ] . But I want same as string format order. So How can I prevent Default order.

Comment: It may help if you include details on the resulting ArrayCollection.  You have limited ability to control the conversion.  Your best bet may be to sort the ArrayCollection after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what you've described here is an array of objects (your example just includes one object).  In the JSON parsing to array, each object is indeed in the order in which it is declared; but in the OBJECTS that are created, the properties may not be listed in the same order.

For example:

```
'[ {"Branch":"Corporate", "Department":"Finance", "Cost":"10000", "Attended":"true"},' +
'{"Branch":"Las Vegas", "Department":"Hospitality", "Cost":"20100", "Attended":"false"},' +
'{"Branch":"San Diego", "Department":"Banking", "Cost":"11023", "Attended":"true"}]'
```

Parsing would return arr[0] as the Corporate object, arr[1] as the Las Vegas object, etc.  Iterating through the properties I got:

```
var obj:Object = dp.getItemAt(0);
for (var prop:String in obj) {
    trace(prop + ' is ' + obj[prop]);
}

Department is Finance
Attended is true
Branch is Corporate
Cost is 10000
```